# What is the purpose of assigning the url to the image source in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("<img src="+url+">").appendTo($("body"));
```

In this the total information is in url and then it is appended to body tag.
Why here we use the image source to assign url.

Comment: Is this question why does the <img> tag work the way it does?

Comment: Are you asking why we need to assign the 'src' attribute for an <img> tag to get the picture to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("<img src='"+url+"'>").appendTo("body");
```

more appropriately

```
$("<img>").attr('src', url).appendTo("body");
```

creates an `img` element and sets `src` attribute to URL stored in var `url` and appends to `body` element.

Comment: You can also drop the wrapping of `body` with `$()`.

Answer (score 2):

The URL is the URL of the image resource. We give the `img` its `src` URL so the browser knows what image resource to retrieve and display. That code is taking an HTML snippet, turning it into an element via `$()`, and then appending it to the `body` element of the page.